# 2.4 setup:install - install with 3rd party modules straight away or wait and use setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, setup-upgrade

So as with title, what is best approach when deploying a M2.4 store with 3rd party modules, please see below with both options, but Option 1 we are getting

```
In WebsiteRepository.php line 159:
                                                                     
  The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again
```

Option 1

1. Have all modules in composer or app/code
2. Run setup:install

Option 2

1. Run setup:install without any modules
2. Once install is finished, use composer to require modules
3. Run setup:upgrade

We've got a set of custom modules we've introduced recently, but can't trace down which module is causing us an error in Option 1, but Option 2 works perfectly fine.

Should we just stick to installing the modules after the base setup:install is finished?

Thanks

Comment: You can just use `composer require` and `setup:upgrade`

Comment: Usually thats a plugin on something. I've seen it caused by a plugin assigned in `etc/di.xml` instead of `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

Comment: Yeah, we ended up tracing it to an interface being used, it was updated to use the interfaceFactory instead and install worked fine